# youtube search change the pages token

Tags: youtube-api

While requesting youtube search functionality the token pages are modifying between request (look at prev and next token)

[image: errorYT]

the code of the cycle is the next

```
done = "N"
  
  while (done == "N") :

    request = youtube.search().list(
        part="snippet"
      , q="crime|airport delay|traffic accident|home invasion"
      , publishedBefore =publish_end_date
      , publishedAfter =publish_start_date
      , maxResults=50
      , pageToken=page_token
      , type="video"
    )
    response = request.execute()
    print ('Total results: ' + str(response["pageInfo"]["totalResults"]))
    if 'prevPageToken' in response:
        print ('prevPageToken: ' + response["prevPageToken"])
    else:
        print ('prevPageToken: NO_MORE_PAGES')
    if 'nextPageToken' in response:
        page_token = str(response["nextPageToken"])
        print ('nextPageToken: ' + page_token)
    else:
        page_token = ""
        done = "Y"
        print ('nextPageToken: NO_MORE_PAGES')

    num_posts = response["pageInfo"]["resultsPerPage"]
    if num_posts > batch_size:
      num_posts=batch_size
    print ('Number of posts to download: '  + str(num_posts))
```

Comment: What is your specific question?  That appears to be correct behavior.

Comment: Check the console image:
Prev : None
Next: CDIQAA
Prev  CDIQAQ
Next: CGQQAA

in the second prev must be the first next and it is not correct